# Launch Onenote UWP using Autohotkey

Tags: cmd, autohotkey, onenote

I'm trying to launch onenote UWP from autohotkey but cannot pin down the specific exe file to launch. I ran the onenote uwp and found the name as Microsoft.Office.OneNote_17.7466.57691.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe and the location is C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Office.OneNote_17.7466.57691.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe. But using the following code, I opened the onenote 2016

```
#o::

run "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Office.OneNote_17.7466.57691.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe"

return
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks a lot!

Jason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (untested):

```
Run, onenote:
```

http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/how-open-windows-10-apps-using-shell-commands

**EDIT:**

You can also create a shortcut of this app to run it this way from your script:

```
#o:: Run, %A_Desktop%\OneNote.lnk
```

http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/create-keyboard-shortcuts-windows-10

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried this method and it opened up onenote 2016. I guess that's because I set onenote 2016 as the default app for notes. So I guess "onenote" opens the default app, do you know a specific command that can invoke Onenote UWP?

Comment: is there a way to programmatically launch a Universal App?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: @jayongg, the final solution I do is setting onenote UWP as the default app for .one file and url link, that solves my problem in most of the cases....

Answer (score 8):

If you have configured OneNote UWP to be your default app when clicking the `onenote-cmd://` magnet link, you can write your AutoHotKey script to run this magnet link.

**1. Configure OneNote UWP as your default app for opening a OneNote magnet link:**
[image: Configure OneNote UWP as your default app for opening a OneNote magnet link]

**2. Open OneNote UWP with Windows+O:**

```
#o::
Run, onenote-cmd://
return
```

**3. Open a OneNote UWP Quick Note with Windows+N**

```
#n::
Run, onenote-cmd://quicknote?onOpen=typing
return
```

Answer (score 2):

This code worked for me:

```
Run, onenote-cmd:// ; this opens windows 10 OneNote.
```

And this code works for opening OF365 OneNote:

```
Run, onenote ; opens OF365 OneNote
```